# How to hide controller name on url for devise after sign in path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When I redirect to `main_index_path` from `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` for devise, I get `localhost:3000\main`. How can I have it so that it only shows `localhost:3000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your devise is associated with `Contact` model

*routes.rb*

```
  authenticated :contact do
    root :to => "controller#action"
  end

  unauthenticated :contact do
    devise_scope :contact do
      get "/" => "devise/sessions#new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: But I already have root defined in  devise_scope :user do root to: "devise/sessions#new"  end

Comment: I get the desired behavior if I get '/' => "main#index", as: root, but that messes devise up

Comment: It was I, I downvoted (it can't be removed now either, sorry, otherwise I would take it off), because the answer is completely out of context to the question. Firstly, it assumes `Devise` is bound to `Contact` (which I see no evidence for), and secondly you're routing to `/` which is basically root. If you wanted to use `root` in both `authenticated` && `unauthenticated`, you'd be able to set the path names explicitly (`root to "devise/sessions#new, as: :unauthenticated_root`)

Comment: Routing `/` to `devise/sessions#new` might as well just add `authenticate_user!` in the controller you wish to use as a "root" (as per my `landing` example below).

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't mind having a "facebook" flow (login before anything), you could use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "main#index"

#app/controllers/main_controller.rb
class MainController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

You'd need to change `main_index_path` to `root_path` in the `after_sign_in_path_for` method.

---

**Landing**

If you wanted to have a separate root path (landing page / content pages etc), you'd be able to use the [`authenticate :user`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper%3Aauthenticated) directives from `Devise`:

```
#config/routes.rb
authenticate :user do #-> has to login to see
  root "main#index", as: :authenticated_root #-> url.com
end

unauthenticated :user do #-> if not logged in
  root "application#landing", as: :root #-> url.com
  resources :pages, path: "blog" #-> url.com/blog
end
```

The above will give you the ability to set a "landing" page in `applicationcontroller`, which is shown if the user is not signed in. If the user is authenticated, they'll see the `main#index` when they browse to `url.com`

Comment: What I wanted at the time was what Nithin described. However, I ended up putting `before_action :authenticate_user!` on `application_controller.rb` instead of `main_controller.rb`, and having `root "main#index"` on `routes.rb`